# I don't want textfield to return any string, instead it should just display red error border without error text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Below textfield is getting rendered in the table. I want to implement input validation for textfield. Let's say if it is required, the validation is being implemented but the problem is, because I don't want the text in error, I have done, errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent, fontSize: 0). Then also whenever the validator is getting called the textfield's bottom border shifts a bit upwards which looks ugly.

```
class _TableTextInputFieldComponentState
extends ConsumerState<TableTextInputFieldComponent> {

  TextEditingController textInputController = TextEditingController();
  String columnName = '';
  Map<String, dynamic> columnAccess = {};
  Map<String, dynamic> columnNumberTypeFieldDetail = {};
  bool isrequired = false;
  bool isStrikeThrough = false;
  bool isEmpty = false;
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  String errorMessage = '';

  u/override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    isStrikeThrough = widget.isStrikeThrough;
    if (widget.indexOfRow == 0) {
      isStrikeThrough = false;
    }
    columnNumberTypeFieldDetail = widget.column;
    columnName = columnNumberTypeFieldDetail['name'];
    columnAccess = columnNumberTypeFieldDetail['access'];
    if (columnNumberTypeFieldDetail.containsKey('validators')) {
      if (columnNumberTypeFieldDetail['validators'].containsKey('required')) {
        isrequired = columnNumberTypeFieldDetail['validators']['required'];
      }
    }
    if (widget.value != '' && widget.value != null) {
      textInputController.text =
          widget.value.toString(); // Convert to string if it's a number
    }
    // Add the focusNode listener to update the state
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      updateEmptyState();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  // Extracted method to update the isEmpty state
  void updateEmptyState() {
    setState(() {
      isEmpty = textInputController.text.isEmpty;
    });
  }

  u/override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      //adding height didn't have any effect really.[the textfield is covering all whole datacell, but the moment validator is called, the textfield shrinks and it's bottom border shifts a bit upwards][1]
      height: 200,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: textInputController,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        readOnly: widget.readOnly || isStrikeThrough,
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isStrikeThrough
              ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
              : TextDecoration.none,
        ),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          isCollapsed: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 20, 5, 13),
          errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent, fontSize: 0),
          filled: false,
        ),
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validator: isrequired
            ? (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  errorMessage = 'Text is required';
                  return errorMessage;
                }
                return null;
              }
            : null,
        onChanged: (value) {
          //Handle string input
          value = textInputController.text;
          widget.onValueChangeInTable(
              widget.indexOfRow, value, columnName, columnAccess);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so u only want to show border in red color when the validation failed ? is that you expect

Comment: Yes. But it is always returning string as error text. @MidlajNazar

Comment: in my opinion remove the validator & border from the textfield. make the validation function onchange event in the textfield. and wrap the textfield with container with the border. if the validation failed then change the color of the container border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
SizedBox(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller.textInputController,
        readOnly: false,
        style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isCollapsed: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent, fontSize: 0),
          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2)),
          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2)),
          filled: false,
        ),
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return '';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onChanged: (value) {},
      ),
    )
```